# Skellam: Derivative of CDF

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

The [Skellam distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skellam_distribution) has no closed-form solution for the CDF. I'm in particular interested how $P(x > 0, n, m)$ changes with $n$ and $m$.

That is: How does the probability of a Poisson race being positive change with the two rates.

Denote the two rates by $m$, $n$, and the realizations by $M$, $N$. My approach:

$$ P(M-N > 0) = \sum_{M=0}^\infty \sum_{N=0}^{M-1} Poisson(M, m) Poisson(N, n) \\
= e^{-(n+m)}\sum_{M=0}^\infty \sum_{N=0}^{M-1} \frac{m^M}{M!}\frac{n^N}{N!} $$

Now, the derivative w.r.t $m$:

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial m} = e^{-(m+n)}\sum_{M=0}^\infty \sum_{N=0}^{M-1} \frac{m^M}{M!}\frac{n^N}{N!}(\frac{M}{m}-1) $$

I know that there is in general no closed-form solution for the CDF, but perhaps there is something more I can do with this derivative to make it neater?

Comment: If $p(s,t)=P(N_t>N_s)$ where $N_t$ and $N_s$ are independent Poisson random variables with parameters $t$ and $s$ respectively, then $(s,t)\mapsto p(s,t)$ is increasing with respect to $t$ and decreasing with respect to $s$. Is this your question?

Comment: @Did Ultimately I'm going for an actual solution, not only the sign.

Comment: Then try $$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}p(s,t)=P(N_t=N_s)=e^{-t-s}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(ts)^k}{(k!)^2}$$ and the series can be expressed as the value of the generalized hypergeometric function ${}_0F_1$ at $ts$.

Comment: @Did Oh I just realized $p(s, t)$ is the $pdf$ - I am after the $CDF$: $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}P(N_t \geq N_s)$

Comment: Oh I suggest you read my comments **much** more carefully (where do yu see a PDF, one wonders).

Comment: @Did I missjudged the derivative presented. After *much* more careful reading it is still not clear to me how $\partial_t p(s, t) = P(N_t = N_s)$, when $p(s, t) = P(N_t > N_s)$.

Comment: And what did you try to make this statement "more clear" to you? I mean, the statement in my second comment, since now you pretend to have read it...

Comment: Was there ever a conclusion reached? I don't see an answer to the original question

Comment: @FooBar, do you have a reference for the statement that there's no closed form expression for the CDF?